# Does JExcelAPI works with jre 1.5?

Tags: java, jexcelapi

I've downloaded JExcelAPI version 2.6.12, and I've not been able to run it using JRE 1.5, only with JRE 1.6.

Can anybody confirm this? or maybe point me which version of JExcel works with JRE 1.5? I haven't been able to find it on the JExcel website.

I need to use it in a project which is limited to work with JRE 1.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try Apache POI's HSSF... most projects that do native Excel format use this, in my experience.

http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html

Comment: Thans @iangreen, I've already tested POI, and it is a good option, what I was looking for is to compare both of them. However, it seems I'll keep with POI.